# What is the effect of using syms in finding energy of a signal

Tags: matlab, signals

The signal is

**x[n]= cos(π*n)** for **-4<=n<=4**

otherwise **x[n]= 0**

I wanted to find its energy in matlab

```
n= -4:1:4;
x= cos(pi*n);
y= abs(x).^2;
```

now output y is

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

However, i didn't understand why the output is with brackets

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

when we give symbolic variable to pi

```
n= -4:1:4;
syms pi;
x= cos(pi*n);
y= abs(x).^2;
```

What is the main difference between two codes?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, the vector `y` is symbolic.
When you multiply symbolic `pi` by vector `n`, the whole vector `pi*n` becomes symbolic:

```
syms pi
n = -4:1:4;
pi*n

ans =
[ -4*pi, -3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, 0, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi, 4*pi]
```

When you pass the symbolic `pi*n` argument to `cos`, the function `cos` produces symbolic output. All `sym` arrays are represented in brackets by default in Matlab